# Checkbox is not functioning as a radio button

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm trying to make checkbox as a radio button so that it should select only one value at a time.

**HTML**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="serviceTable in dataTable ">  
    <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceId }} </td>
    <td> {{ serviceTable.serviceName }} </td>
    <td> {{ serviceTable. amount }} </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="serviceId" ng-true-value="{{ serviceTable.serviceId }}" ng-change=" test(serviceTable.serviceId)" ng-required="!{{ serviceTable.serviceId }}"  ></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.test = function(val) {

                   $scope.serviceId = val;

                    }
```

It is allowing to select multiple checkboxes. Any solution?

Comment: Can't you use radio button rather than hacking around checkbox. If you are supporting only one selection semantically radio button is more correct

Comment: @PSL No I need checkbox feature